# Join some values having the same code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SELECT on SQL Server 2014 Express:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, Lastname, Phone1, Phone2, Phone3, ... PhoneN
FROM TableX
WHERE Phone1 <> ''
```

And the results now are like:

```
Name  Lastname  Phone1     Phone2     Phone3     ...
James Brown     68798768
James Brown     98761456
Alice Grey      66687974
Peter Thompson  87997555
Peter Thompson  87997444
Peter Thompson  87997333
```

And I need a SELECT that returns me them gruping the phones of the people with the same name like this:

```
Name  Lastname  Phone1     Phone2     Phone3     ...
James Brown     68798768   98761456
Alice Grey      66687974
Peter Thompson  87997555   87997444   87997333
```

Any query?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of phone numbers?

Comment: Would a single string of numbers in CSV  format be OK?

Comment: I have a max of 10

Comment: Are your `Phone#` fields, other than `Phone1`, all currently `NULL` or do some already have values in them?

Comment: Poor table design.

Comment: I know but it's not mine and not editable, closed source, blackbox.
They are null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a maximum number of phones and you don't need to go DYNAMIC, a conditional aggregation may do the trick

```
Select Name
      ,LastName
      ,Phone1 = max(case when RN=1 then Phone1 else '' end)
      ,Phone2 = max(case when RN=2 then Phone1 else '' end)
      ,Phone3 = max(case when RN=3 then Phone1 else '' end)
      ,Phone4 = max(case when RN=4 then Phone1 else '' end)
From  (
        Select *
              ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By Name,LastName Order By Phone1)
        From  YourTable
       ) A
 Group By Name,LastName
```

Comment: Was looking for you :)

Comment: @GurwinderSingh HA!  Not DYNAMIC  :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try, I have a max of 10

Comment: @jinfo As you can see it would be easy to expand.  I'm confident that you will have no issues.  Honestly, it is well worth your time to get get comfortable with the window functions.  They can be invaluable.  Cheers

Comment: @jinfo. You will need to extend John's SELECT to Phone5, Phone6 and so on to meet your requirement.

Comment: @jinfo Happy it helped.  Sorry about the initial typo  :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering you only have a maximum of 10 phone numbers you can do something like....

```
Select *
FROM (
       Select * 
          ,'Phone-' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, LastName 
                        ORDER BY Phone1) AS VARCHAR(10)) PhoneNum
       FROM TableName
   ) t
PIVOT (MAX(Phone1)
       FOR PhoneNum
       IN ([Phone-1],[Phone-2],[Phone-3],[Phone-4],[Phone-5],
          [Phone-6],[Phone-7],[Phone-8],[Phone-9],[Phone-10])
       )p
```